# edit all hrefs in the page with jquery

Tags: jquery, href

there are hyperlinks in my page link this

```
<a href="home.php?id=2">some text</a>
<a href="http://myDomanin.com/home.php?id=3">some text</a>
<a href="http://myDomanin.com/home.php?id=4">some text</a>
<a href="home.php?id=5">some text</a>
```

I want to write a javascript to change hrefs to this new link:

if `OldHref = http://myDomanin.com/home.php?id=3` then

`NewHref = http://myNewDomain.com/{base64Encode of OldHref}`

found a plugin to make base64 encode [here](http://hpyer.cn/codes/jquery-plugin-base64-encode-and-decode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function(){
  this.href = 'http://myNewDomain.com/' + Base64Encode(this.href);
});
```

Or something of the sort...

---

Non, jQuery method:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var a = 0; a < anchors.length; a++){
  anchors[a].href = 'http://myNewDomain.com/' + Base64Encode(anchors[a].href);
}
```